# Airflow Long (time) URL request not receiving response

Tags: python-requests, airflow

I'm setting up a DAG in airflow (Cloud Composer) to trigger some Cloud Run jobs that take upwards of 30 mins to complete.

Instead of using SimpleHTTPOperator, I'm using the pythonOperator to obtain a OIDC token to allow me to trigger services that require automation.

```
    def make_authorized_get_request(service_url, **kwargs):

        auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
        id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, service_url)

        headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {id_token}"}
        req = requests.get(service_url, headers=headers, timeout=(5, 3600))
        status = req.status_code
        response_json = req.json()
    
        return response_json,status
    
    #t1 as request first report
    big3_request = PythonOperator(
        task_id='big3_request',
        python_callable=make_authorized_get_request,
        op_kwargs={"service_url":"cloud run url"}
    )
```

I can see the cloud run job completes successfully, but the task in airflow doesn't seem to pick up on the response (a json containing some data about the job and a status code) and just keeps on running, unless a timeout is set, in which case it errors (although the response should be available by then).

I've pointed this task towards a shorter service to test and it picks up response fine.

How can I get the task to pick up on the response? Or do I need to use another operator?